# Strange behaviour of CGPathGetBoundingBox

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics

This very simple code...

```
CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(-50, -50, 100, 100), NULL);
NSLog(@"Original path bounds = %@", NSStringFromRect(CGPathGetBoundingBox(path)));
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.75 * M_PI);
CGPathRef tPath = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(path, &t);
NSLog(@"Transformed path bounds = %@", NSStringFromRect(CGPathGetBoundingBox(tPath)));
CGPathRelease(path);
CGPathRelease(tPath);
```

...produces the following strange output:

```
[...] Original path bounds = {{-50, -50}, {100, 100}}
[...] Transformed path bounds = {{-54.881553646890872, -54.881553646890872}, {109.76310729378174, 109.76310729378174}}
```

Since it's a circle centred on (0,0), shouldn't any rotation preserve the original bounding box? Why on earth has the bounding box grown? Or is it an Apple bug?

Comment: I found out what the problem was. CGPathGetBoundingBox() includes the control points of the Bezier curve used to create the path. If I replace it with CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(), then it all works as expected, because that function doesn't include the control points.

Comment: When you can, you should post that as an answer to your own question and accept it (unless someone else gives a better answer before that).

Comment: Done, just need to wait until tomorrow to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the `CGPathGetBoundingBox()` function includes the control points of the Bezier curves that are used to construct the circle. These control points reside outside the circle, and so when you rotate the circle they will naturally end up outside the original bounding box.

The solution is to use to use the `CGPathGetPathBoundingBox()` function, which does *not* include the control points in its calculation of the path's bounding box.